# Null pointer en un intent en su segunda llamada

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-intent, android-context

Este método que está en un fragment, quiere hacer que busque en la base de datos personas que como el usuario quieran iniciar una conversación con una persona aleatoria. Por eso hay un intent que salta a la activity del chat. Con una primera búsqueda no hay problema, encuentra otro usuario y lleva al chat, pero después de que siga utilizando la app y vuelvo a ese mismo fragment, aparece un error que cierra la aplicación. Son problemas con el context, tengo otro bug que creo que está relacionado con eso que tampoco consigo solucionar ya que no tengo un gran dominio de ese concepto.  No entiendo porque es, tanto en esta ocasión como en el otro bug, cuando se usa la app se pasa a otra parte y da el error al volver. Adjunto tanto el método como el error, si necesitáis algo más lo puedo poner sin problema.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:130)
    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:5847)
    at com.example.blindchat2.menu.ForumFragment$7.onDataChange(ForumFragment.java:238)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Método:

```
 private void randomChat(){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("schat","searching");
    reference.updateChildren(hashMap); //Con esto hago que el usuario pase a estar en la lista de buscar chat aleatorio
    search.setText(R.string.searching);



    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("schat")
            .startAt("searching")

            .endAt("searching"+"\uf8ff");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                if(!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){ //Compruebo que la persona que encuentro no es el propio usuario
                    hashMap.put("schat","none"); //Actualizo a none para que no lo encuentren
                    reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MessageActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("userid", user.getId());            
                    startActivity(intent);
                    search.setText(R.string.search_chat);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: En qué clase está la función randomChat?

Comment: @Mateo está en un fragment llamado ForumFragment, que a este se accede mediante el MainActivity

Comment: Prueba reemplazar `getContext()` por `getActivity()`. Creo que no se solucionará solo con eso porque está dentro de una clase anónima pero quiero sacarme la duda.

Comment: @Mateo produce exactamente el mismo error

Answer (score 1):

Tal como están las cosas, se me ocurre que sean 2 las razones por las que el Activity no se inicia:

1. Estás intentando iniciarla desde un Fragment.

La solución para este punto consta de usar `getActivity()`.

2. Además, lo estás haciendo desde una clase anónima.

Recordemos que las clases anónimas son aquellas que no se definen con un nombre ni en un archivo propio, no tienen modificador de acceso y no se pueden heredar (no confundir con clases anidadas). Lo que sí tienen cada una, es un contexto propio. Por lo que `this` hará referencia a la instancia de una u otra clase.

Por si no logras diferenciarlas, aquí un ejemplo:

```
public class ClaseNormal {
    ...
    public void funcion(){
        this.getClass(); // ClaseNormal
        
        // Esta es una clase anónima
        new OtraClase(){
            @Override
            public void saluda(){
                this.getClass(); // ClaseNormal$1 - Aparece un número porque es una clase anónima
                System.out.println("Bienvenido");
            }
        };
    }
    ...
    public class ClaseAnidada {
       ...
    }
}

public class OtraClase {
    public void saluda(){
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

Cuando creas una clase anónima y quieres acceder a la instancia de la clase exterior, se resuelve de una manera simple. Haces referencia a la exterior con `Clase.this`. Retomando el ejemplo anterior:

```
...
new OtraClase(){
    @Override
    public void saluda(){
        this.getClass() // ClaseNormal$1 - Aparece un número porque es una clase anónima
        ClaseNormal.this.getClass() // ClaseNormal
        System.out.println("Bienvenido");
    }
};
```

Dicho todo esto, el Activity debería iniciarse luego de reemplazar la línea del Intent por esta:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ForumFragment.this.getActivity(), MessageActivity.class);
```

Comment: he cambiado lo que me has dicho y sigue habiendo el problema. Para darte más información la pantalla es como instagram, son diferentes fragments los cuales cada uno tiene una finalidad. Entonces al dar en ForumFragment y genero un chat no hay problema, pero cuando salto a otra y vuelvo a ForumFragment y vuelvo a generar es cuando salta el error. Es en este caso particular, no sé si esto te da más información.

Comment: No  se me ocurre qué más podría ser